# How to Make My Equation Look Better With Text

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

I am creating a calculus study guide with LaTeX. I want my equations to be left aligned, but with the added text everything sort of looks terrible (not really left aligned and quite jagged in my opinion). Is there a better way to get left aligned equations that still look good?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{Definite Integration}
\begin{align*}
  \int_a^b f(x) dx &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\Delta x\\
  \int_a^a f(x) dx &= 0\\
  \int_a^b f(x) dx &= -\int_b^a f(x) dx\\
  \int_a^b cf(x) dx &= c\int_a^b f(x) dx\\
  \int_a^b (f(x) \pm g(x)) dx &= \int_a^b f(x) dx \pm \int_a^b g(x) dx\\
  \int_a^p f(x) dx + \int_p^b f(x) dx &= \int_a^b f(x) dx\\
  \text{If } f(x) > g(x) \text{ on the interval } [a,b] &\text{ then } \int_a^b f(x) dx > \int_a^b g(x) dx
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the fragment `If $f(x) > g(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$, then` inside an `\intertext` directive. You should also insert thinspaces ahead of the `dx` terms in the integrals.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{Definite Integration}
\begin{align*}
  \int_a^b f(x)\,dx &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\Delta x\\
  \int_a^a f(x)\,dx &= 0\\
  \int_a^b f(x)\,dx &= -\int_b^a f(x)\,dx\\
  \int_a^b cf(x)\,dx &= c\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\\
  \int_a^b \bigl(f(x) \pm g(x)\bigr)\,dx &= \int_a^b f(x)\,dx \pm \int_a^b g(x)\,dx\\
  \int_a^p f(x)\,dx + \int_p^b f(x)\,dx &= \int_a^b f(x)\,dx\\
\intertext{If $f(x) > g(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$, then} 
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx &> \int_a^b g(x)\,dx
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Whoa intertext. That's new to me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The following example sets the left part of the equations left aligned and keeps the alignment of the equal signs. The text below is set as normal text with inline math.

Also the example uses `\diff` for the differential operator, which improves the horizontal spacing by adding a little space before depending on the previous math atom.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

% Better horizontal spacing
\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}
\section{Definite Integration}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &\int_a^b f(x) \diff x
    &&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\,\Delta x\\
  &\int_a^a f(x) \diff x &&= 0\\
  &\int_a^b f(x) \diff x &&= -\int_b^a f(x) \diff x\\
  &\int_a^b cf(x) \diff x &&= c\int_a^b f(x) \diff x\\
  &\int_a^b (f(x) \pm g(x)) \diff x
    &&= \int_a^b f(x) \diff x \pm \int_a^b g(x) \diff x\\
  &\int_a^p f(x) \diff x + \int_p^b f(x) \diff x &&= \int_a^b f(x) \diff x
\end{alignat*}
  If $f(x) > g(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$ then
  $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) \diff x > \int_a^b g(x) \diff x$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the diff operator. Hard to say which I like better between the two alignments. Perhaps I'll use a mix of both